# numbers have been masked with asterisk Asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a very strange issue, some numbers in webpage have been marked with "*" randomly.
Issue happened with asp.net 4 webform & IIS Server 7.
I have no clue why this happen.

E.g:
Our text in textbox: 45-379100040007917
After postback it will display: 45-***************

Did you ever encouter this issue ? thank you very much for your help !

Comment: There are various 3rd party textbox controls which can mask the input. Looks like this might be happening to you i.e. there's some javascript running on the page which is masking the long number as it's assuming it's a credit card number.

Please show your web page markup so we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it happend in all pages, and we are using  standard asp.net textbox control. It's very weird. we suspect issue comes from IIS server but still got no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using some products in your Http pipeline that converts certain pattern of text into masked text.

An example of which is below.
https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/irule-ccn-scrubber

The rule above will look for credit card patterns in your Html response and replace it.

Goodluck.